# How to print an int with comma divisors using a recursive method (no strings)?

Tags: java, recursion, number-formatting

In my computer science class, we were assigned a lab on recursion in which we have to print out a number with commas separating groups of 3 digits.
Here is the text directly from the assignment (the method has to be recursive):

> Write a method called printWithCommas that takes a single nonnegative
> primitive int argument and displays it with commas inserted properly.
> No use of String.
>
> For example printWithCommas(12045670); Displays 12,045,670
>
> printWithCommas(1); Displays 1

I am really stumped on this. Here is my code so far:

```
    public static void printWithCommas(int num) {
    //Find length
    if (num < 0) return;
    int length = 1;
    if (num != 0) {
        length = (int)(Math.log10(num)+1);
    }
    //Print out leading digits
    int numOfDigits = 1;
    if (length % 3 == 0) {
        numOfDigits = 3;
    }
    else if ((length+1) % 3 == 0) {
        numOfDigits = 2;
    }
    System.out.print(num / power(10,length-numOfDigits));
    //Print out comma
    if (length > 3) {
        System.out.print(',');
    }
    printWithCommas(num % power(10,length-numOfDigits));
}
```

It gets a stack overflow (which I can fix later), but it fails to print out some of the zeros, specifically the ones that are supposed to be after each comma.

I feel like I am taking this on with a completely wrong approach, but can't think of a good one. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Note: `power` is a function I made that calculates power. First argument is the base, second is the exponent.

Comment: You realise that there is already a function in Java that calculates powers?

Comment: @BenWainwright We had to implement our own. Technically, the log im using is violating the lab's rules, so I'll have to fix that later too.

Comment: Ok, there is a much better way of doing this, but I feel that if I give you the solution I've just written, I'd be essentially doing your lab for you. So here's a few hints: Delete a digit from number `n` by doing `n / 10`. To retrieve that digit do `n % 10`

Comment: @BenWainwright I thought of that before, but didn't get anything from it.

Comment: Try creating a recursive function method that simply prints the digits out one by one, aka each call of the method is responsible for printing an individual digit. Once you have done that, work what you can do to get the commas in the right place. Remember that if you don't have enough information in your function signature, you can create a 'helper function' that does the recursion and takes extra arguments; that is a fairly common pattern.

Comment: To prevent stack overflow change your break condition to `if (num <= 0)`

Comment: But still your algorithm won't work with `12045009` number.

Comment: @arsendavtyan91 thanks.

Comment: @arsendavtyan91 I know, the zeros don't print right. That is why I made this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I came up with, for anyone else that might be stuck on this:

```
public static void printWithCommas(int num) {
    if (num > 999) {
        printWithCommas(num/1000);
        System.out.print(',');
        if (num % 1000 < 100) System.out.print('0');
        if (num % 1000 < 10) System.out.print('0');
        System.out.print(num%1000);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(num);
    }
}
```